# Jshint tells there's a warning in ternary operators

Tags: javascript, marionette, jslint, jshint

So I'm starting to use jshint and it gives me a warning at the line with the ternary operator.

```
crossIconClicked: function (e){
            //if W3C_standard ? stopPropagation_for_standard : for_Old_IExplorer
            e.stopPropagation ? e.stopPropagation() : (e.cancelBubble=true);
            this.shareClickEvent(e);
},
```

Yes, `crossIconClicked` is an `event handler`, and `e` is the `Event`.

The warning is:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
>   (W030)

Why should I refrain from using ternary operator ? What's wrong with the line.

I don't want to supress the warning, just knowing what is the 'danger' here.

Comment: It's just an "opinion" that jshint has. You can (probably) disable that test if you disagree.

Comment: Try removing the parentheses around `e.cancelBubble = true`. The parentheses cause it to be evaluated as an expression, which is unnecessary.

Comment: @4castle — It's *supposed* to be evaluated as an expression.

Comment: @Quentin Does it behave any differently as an expression? There's an example just like this one on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), but without parentheses.

Comment: @4castle — Removing the parentheses still leaves it as an expression, the operator precedence is just less obvious.

Comment: yes, the parentheses is unnecessary. But it seems that jshint is complaining about left hand side as @Quentin answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ternary expression has no left hand side. It is designed to take one of two values and put that value somewhere.

You are using it as a simple `if` statement.

Comment: so long story short:  `<first> ? <second> : <third>`  

.  
Where `<first>` needs to be an assigment ? @Quentin

Comment: No, `something = <first> ? <second> : <third>`